# TFS hangs at "Performing add on [foo]" dialog when checking in new files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have 16 files that were added to our Team Foundation Server Source Control repo as part of a larger add/checkin that remain un-check-inable.

Nothing special about the files--text files, xml files, xls files, no funky names, and the Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer check in hangs when either a single one or all are attempted to be checked in.

The add works w/o problems (though some but not all show as "add, lock" state?!). When Check In Pending Changes is attempted, and the files in question are selected, the check in dialog will hang at "Performing add on [first file in group of 16 that was selected for checkin]...". devenv.exe has to be killed to recover from the hang.

This is reproducible with the files in question (undo pending changes, add items to folder, check in pending changes).

Comment: in the output window, select "Show output from source control - team foundation" and see if there are any messages in there.

Comment: "add,lock" means it's a filetype that is configured for mutually exclusive access (usually binary files - if one user edits the file, it cannot be merged if another edits it, so it is locked to only allow one checkout). Are any of the files huge? Can you check them in to a different folder, or do they always fail?)

Comment: My suggestion is to check the event log on your Application Tier server and see what's timing out.  The event log messages can be both cryptic and informative at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the hints about the console output and the event log on the server.

In the end, the problem was a corruption in the server state vs local state for the files in question. The server saw them as fully checked in (which they weren't, the actual files were not on the server yet), while the local version saw them as not yet checked in to the server (thus not matching with the server's versioning state).

We resolved by performing a lock or unlock on each of the files. This forced the server to recognize the unchanged state of the local version, and forced the local version to sync with the server. The check ins proceeded without error afterwards.